# Samsung S10e with LineageOS 19.1 won't boot anymore

Tags: samsung, boot-loop, lineageos

This morning I rebooted my phone cause battery usage was too high. No update was applied before, just a regular reboot.

Since then the phone only shows the LineageOS bootscreen and after 2 tries it boots to recovery.

I already tried installing the latest LineageOS 19.1 again. That seemed to work but the bootloop is still there.

Unfortunately the latest backup is a bit older and I would at least like to recover various chats.

Is there any way to backup from recovery? adb backup doesn't work. With TWRP it was easy but since Android 12 the encryption seems to be an issue.

If I do a factory reset I will likely also lose everything on the data partition. Pictures, WhatsApp backup, ...

Any idea?

adb logcat won't even connect to the phone, so adb won't be started. Seems to fail in an early stage.